# Google Font APIs 'Montserrat' font color becomes light in firefox 88.0

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I have my `custom.css` and inside this file I am using this Google Font `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700);` and until yesterday I was working fine in my **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Firefox version 88.0**.

But today when I opened the website, the font color getting light like below.

[image]

The strange thing I have noticed is, its not happening with new Firefox versions (like versions above 100) in Ubuntu. Its also working fine in Google Chrome and in other browsers.

Its only happening versions below 100 or at-least in version 88.0 which I have in Ubuntu.

I have also researched and found out this thread https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36986 which suggests me to replace the CSS with something like below which I did.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=optimal);
```

But here I have noticed that this font name is not the same. I have `Montserrat` and here in the code it has `Nunito`. Additionally, when I refreshed the page, my web page menu also became bold. So I believe this is not working fine.

Can someone guide me how can I apply the same font which wont break my bold italic and other options like I already have.

Any help or guidance or support will be highly appreciated.

Thanks